# How to fix undefined variable: Products in view blade Laravel 9.50.1

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-9

I am using Laravel 9.50.1, and I am building a shopping cart. However, when I want to display my shop products dynamically on the website after creating database tables and database seeder, I get an undefined $product variable. Initially, I could show my shop products before I created the controller to return the view. What am I doing wrong? Please help!

**Controller**

```
public function products()
{
    $products = $product::all();
    
    return view('products', compact('products'));
}
```

**Blade/view**

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')

    @foreach($products->
        chunk(3) as $chunk)
        <div class="card-deck">
            @foreach($chunk as $product)
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title text-primary">
                            {{$product->name}}
                            <strong>
                                ${{$product->price}}
                            </strong></h5>
                        <a href="{{route('add-to-cart', $products->id)}}"
                           class="btn btn-warning">
                            Add to cart</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endforeach

@endsection
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\ShoppingCartController@products')->name('products');
```

Comment: You have used capital letters, Please check again like  this: products

Comment: Are blade laravel 9.50.1 variables case in-sensitive? Could you please provide reference to the blade laravel 9.50.1 manual regarding this point? Why do you think it should work?

Comment: i have'nt used uppercase letters

Comment: yes the blade laravel 9.50.1 are case sensitive